# Подскажите Python IDE для разработки GUI

Tags: python, gui, поиск-программ

А именно я имею в виду для самостоятельного размещения виджетов. Что-то подобное:

[image: К примеру что подобное к этому:]

Comment: В QtDisegner можно сделать то, что вам нужно, а потом его конвертировать  в py формат

Comment: практически для каждой GUI библиотеки есть GUI layout, form designers (e.g., qt, kivy, tkinter). В зависимости от задачи можно браузеры в качестве GUI использовать (и соответствующие инструменты).

Answer (score 2):

QT Designer для этой задачи подойдет. Там накидаете дизайн, а потом уже допишете функционал. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dmo8eZG5I2w - вот быстрый тьюториал в ютьюбе, правда на английском.